# Generic interface compiles but does not work at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have an issue with generic interface. The compiler does not give any compiling errors but at run-time unseen exception is thrown.

```
public interface IStructure
{
    string Name {get;}
}

public interface IStructureNavigation<T> : IStructure where T : IStructure
{
    T Parrent {get;}
}


public class ResourceStructure : IStructureNavigation<ResourceStructure>
{
    private ResourceStructure _parrent;

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual ResourceStructure Parrent
    {
        get { return _parrent; }
    }

}
```

Can someone explain why does the following code fail at runtime?

```
public class Action
{
    private ObjectContext _context;
    private ObjectSet<ResourceStructure> _structue;
    private IQueryable<ResourceStructure > _parrents;

    public Action()
    {
        string connectionString =
             ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["Structure"].ConnectionString;

        _context = new ObjectContext(connectionString);
        _context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

        _structue = _context.CreateObjectSet<ResourceStructure>();
        _parrents = _structue.Where(x => x.ParentID == null);


       // FAILS IN FOREACH LOOP : UNSEEN EXCPTION
       foreach (IStructureNavigation<IStructure> strt in _parrents)
        {
            //do something
        }


       //WORKS IF USING CONCRETE TYPE NOT INTERFACE
       foreach(IStructureNavigation<ResourceStructure > strt in _parrents)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "unseen exception"?  How exactly does it fail?

Comment: Look into how you might support *interface covariance*.

Comment: `IStructureNavigation<ResourceStructure>` is not a `IStructureNavigation<ResourceStructure>`

Comment: @sll one of those should read IStructureNavigation<IStructure>

Comment: "Unseen excepiton" = nothing happens really. The code just jumps over foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your instance is of type `IStructureNavigator<ResourceStructure>` and not `IStructureNavigator<IStructure>`.

If you need to use the interface, you can use the Cast extension method:

```
_parrents =  _context.CreateObjectSet<ResourceStructure>().Cast<IStructure>();
```

Which version of the Framework are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Declare T as covariant

```
  public interface IStructureNavigation<out T> : IStructure where T : IStructure
```

Comment: Thanks for a tip, I will look forward about interface covariance. I Did not even know about this.

Comment: Not a lot to look into, if you simply add the out keyword as above to your code as is will work (providing you are on .NET 4?).  The cast solution works, but is not type safe, e.g. it will always compile but could fail at runtime if your class/interface heirarchy changes.  Using covariance this would be picked up at compile time.